# backbone.js examples

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, user-interface, prototype

I've just started looking at backbone.js/underscore, with jquery and require.js. I'm interested to hear other people's experience with this stack.

I want to build a fast front end prototyping setup that will let me do a bunch of similar types of app front ends quickly.

Any productive comments about other alternatives are welcome.  Pointers to examples would be appreciated.

I've already gotten good word about Ember.js and will give it a try soon.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Backbone.js Todo app](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html), pretty much the "Hello world" of JavaScript MVC. It's a good introduction to Backbone. After that, there's a ton of Backbone stuff out there -- you should have no trouble finding things. Use Google. Use Google often.

Answer (score 0):

Don't take my word for it, just look at some of the more impressive sites out there today. I make an effort, when coming across a site I like, to try determine the tech stack involved. I can say with confidence that most of the sites I look at, base their client side foundation off Backbone. I have never tried Ember or Angular, but I believe a Modular Backbone tech stack to be a solid choosing when building web apps. Backbone also has an awesome community and excellent documentation. You should be able to find solutions to problems very quickly. Here are some sites using Backbone.

[Chrysler](http://testofownership.com/) |
[Hulu](http://www.hulu.com/) |
[USA Today](http://beta.usatoday.com/)